# Hudson dependent job

Tags: java, hudson

I have such a situation : one hudson job for one project that is running by polling SCM, and another hudson job for release of the project. On second job for release we do not want to run IT tests multiple times, so we before release we want to run one with job and if will be not failed we will run release job. 
It is possible to setup release hudson job to run another job and only in case if it finished successfully start running itself?
Thx

Update:
I have job A and job B. Job A could be run anytime by everyone and it should not trigger any other job2. But if i want to run Job B i need that after i click run B it should  trigger job A and only in case if job A finishes successfully job B starts it's own execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know, with a default installation this is not possible. But you can use the Join trigger plugin. You then have to create a new job, for example "Create release". This job triggers job A for the tests (with "Build other projects", and then in the "Post-Build Actions" of that new job you define the "Join Trigger" to run job B.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a build that runs your automated tests, and another build that creates your release. You want to have them interdependent, such that if the automated tests fail, the release build is not re-built.

I would approach this differently. Hudson has a feature where you can archive the "last successful artifacts". If you do this correctly, you can archive your binaries created during the testing run and use these artifacts to push out your release. In this way, even a broken testing build will not affect your "last successful artifacts" and your release will go ahead with an older, successful set of binaries.